# Rails: Belongs_to Polymorphic Association + conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relationships

So I have this model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :to_id, :to_type

  belongs_to :to, polymorphic: true

end
```

I was wondering if I could add another relationship when belongs_to is on a specific type:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :to_id, :to_type

  belongs_to :to, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :to_user, :foreign_key => :to_id, :conditions => ['to_type = ?', 'User'] # doesn't work
  # OR MAYBE
  belongs_to :to_user, :foreign_key => :to_id, :foreign_class => 'User' # It doesn't check on Model's to_type...
end
```

So that `my_model.to_user` would return the `user` if exists, and `nil` if unset or of different class.

Using Rails 3.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use where condition inside that like

```
 belongs_to :to_user,-> {where(:to_type=> 'User')},  :foreign_key => :to_id
```

Form more have a look on this [association callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks)

Comment: I use Rails 4.2.7.1 and when I called `model.to_user` I got `uninitialized constant Model::ToUser` error

Comment: Might need to set `inverse_of: :to_user` @ddanurwenda [inverse](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) see "Setting Inverses".

Answer (score 0):

for such a case, and assuming I understood your question, I would probably add a separate method for clarity.

```
def to_user
  #user-exclusive association retrieval
  type =  self.to_type == 'User'
  User.find(self.to_id) if type
end
```